# Count a class on document ready

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a registration form. On that form, the first name and last name is required.
Instead of `require attr`, I also add a class named `has-required`, that class will change border of text field to red.
On  I did `remove has-required class` when people fill the text, and on

```
$('.has-required').change(function(){
if($('.has-required').size() == 0) alert('no text found')
else ('class has required found')
});
```

However, when I go to other page and back to this page, I count class has-required and result is 2.
I need that result is 0, is there any ways to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Then, you need to use ajax.

Comment: Side-note: use `.length` instead of `.size()`

Comment: u mean , if USER didnt fill textbox,then show him has-required class,else not ,correct?

Comment: _when I go to other page and back to this page_......when this happens all the js changes set to default again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
$(function() {
    function mark() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('has-required', !!$this.val();)         
    }

    $('.has-required').change(mark) //add onchange listener
                      .each(mark); //check fields on DOM ready.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.has-required').change(function(){
   if('' !== $.trim($(this).val()){
      $(this).removeClass('has-required')
   }
});
```